# React Native Example App symlinking module not working

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

So I've got a react-native module I'm building in it's own repo. In this repo, I've included an example app of how it can be used and I've specified it like this in my ExampleApp's package.json:

```
 "my-module": "file:../"
```

I'm using [metro-with-symlinks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metro-with-symlinks) which works great for hot reloading my example app when I'm editing my module's source code.

Problem I'm running into now is that I've just added a dependency on my module on `@react-native-community/async-storage`, like so:

```
// my-module package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1"
    ...
}
```

Now, whenever I start my example app, I get `Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.` So my example app isn't linking this dependency and I don't know how to make it do so. I can see this when I do a pod install in my example app because the async storage dependency isn't showing up.

Is there any way to get this set up working?

EDIT: I've seen people in my org use peerDependencies for react-native modules like this and require the application to supply the RN module. Is that the "correct" way to go about it for react-native. It doesn't feel very "peerDependency" to me, but maybe this is how RN modules should be developed?